# Winsock Bluetooth subsequent calls to send function fails with WSAECONNABORTED

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bluetooth, winsock2

I am trying to create simple windows bluetooth **client** application. However after successfull connect the send() function is sending data only for a short duration. The subsequent calls to send() function fail with code: 10053 (WSAECONNABORTED).

From docs:

> Software caused connection abort. An established connection was aborted by the software in your host computer, possibly due to a data transmission time-out or protocol error.

If I understand it correctly the error is occuring on Windows (client) side and not on the server side?
What could be causing it?
Also is it possible to somehow reconnect this socket?

The code (simplified, missing error checks):

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2bth.h>
#include <iostream>

// {B62C4E8D-62CC-404b-BBBF-BF3E3BBB1374} ]taken from Microsoft example
DEFINE_GUID(gGuidServiceClass, 0xb62c4e8d, 0x62cc, 0x404b, 0xbb, 0xbf, 0xbf, 0x3e, 0x3b, 0xbb, 0x13, 0x74);

unsigned char dummyData [10] =
{
  0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05,
  0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05 
};

int main(void)
{
    WSAData wsaData = {0};
    SOCKADDR_BTH btAddr = {0};
    uint32_t flags = 0;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    btAddr.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
    btAddr.serviceClassId = gGuidServiceClass;
    btAddr.port = 0;
    btAddr.btAddr = // hardcoded address here
    SOCKET s = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
    if (SOCKET_ERROR == connect(s, (struct sockaddr *) &btAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH)))
    {
        std::cout << "socket connect fail: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    int32_t bytes = send(s, reinterpret_cast<char *>(dummyData), 10, 0);
    if (bytes == 10)
    {
      std::cout << "first send success\n";
    }
    // success
    // do some processing
    // repeat
    bytes = send(s, reinterpret_cast<char *>(dummyData), 10, 0);
    if (bytes < 0)
    {
        // always fail with 10053
        std::cout << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One of possible reason: wrong data so buffer overflow appears on server side or server simple drops the connection because of wrong data.

Comment: Move your calls to `WSAGetLastError` right after you determined that it will return a meaningful value. Don't have **any** interleaving calls that might change it.

Comment: The client code does not see the problem, please add the server code in the question.